# Converting void*

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I'm really raw with C, and am having trouble with a cast. Here are the lines of my code that I think are relevant:

```
#define BUF 1025
char hostname[BUF];

hostname = *(char *) qpop(&queue);
```

And this is the error that I am getting from the compiler:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[1025]' from
>   type char

Note that the function qpop returns a void*. I think that my issue is how to cast from a void* into char[1025]. From the error message, I seem to be casting to type char, but not to type char[1025]. I tried this:

```
hostname = *(char[1025] *) qpop(&queue)
```

but that didn't work either.

Can somebody help me understand how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: the proper way to cast is without the first asterisk: char_ptr=(char*)void_ptr;

Comment: @NannuoLei: Actually, the *proper* way is to not cast at all. `void*` needs no casting to assign it to another pointer type. Additionally, the extra `*` isn't doing any casting at all, it's doing a dereference.

Comment: @Cornstalks thanks for the enlightenment. I know you're right about void, I just forgot about that and stepped directly into explaining how to cast anything (other than void*). And yes, the first * is for dereference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are not first-class types. You cannot assign to an array. You have to copy the memory/elements into the array:

```
memcpy(hostname, qpop(&queue), BUF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting does not make sense. because you can't assign a pointer to array directly. FYI the syntax is :`hostname = (char(*)[1025]) qpop(&queue)` . you can read this as "pointer to array of 1025 chars"

The best Solution is give by @Cornstalks

Comment: `*char[1025]` is not a valid type name. The type name of a pointer to an array `1025` of `char` is `char (*)[1025]`. This anyway has no sense as you cannot assign to an array and assuming you could, you would not assign a pointer as the right operand.

Comment: oops yes you are right. made the correction . actually i never use it for casting so forget the syntax.